# Android Studio w/ app engine plugin error

Tags: android

Did anybody get this error I've been banging my head for 3 days now trying to get Android Studio with app engine to work (from the Android Studio Event Log):

Plugin Error
            Problems found loading plugins:

```
        Plugin "Google App Engine Integration" was not loaded: required plugin "com.intellij.javaee" not installed.
        Disable Google App Engine Integration
        Open plugin manager
```

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using to generate the AppEngine backend?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Deleting the .AndroidStudioBeta folder in my home directory and reinstalling Android Studio 0.8.9 resolved my issues.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that and comment later the result.

Comment: I deleted the .AndroidStudioBeta folder in my home directory and reinstalled Studio 0.8.6 and also tried 0.8.14 but NO CIGAR...I'm not sure if I need this 'Google App Engine Integration' plugin for enhancing the JDO classes...

Comment: I don't think the plugin is actually compatible with Android Studio. :/ https://plus.google.com/118410017054839996749/posts/fqSfuTBWPtx